# Python datetime utcnow vs Luxon Datetime.fromMillis?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, luxon

I'm trying to wrap my head in understanding the *implication* of using `.utcnow` vs. `.now` on Python's DateTime.

Here's the reason for my confusion: I live in France. Right now, we have a +1 hour on the UTC timezone (CET timezone in winter (now) / CEST (+2) timezone in summer).

If I take the following value :

```
dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
dt.strftime('%c') # Thu Dec  9 16:17:38 2021
int(dt.timestamp()) # 1639063064
```

This is correct as it is, in France right now, 17h17.
So, from my understanding, that timestamp, `1639063064`, is the UTC representation of the time since EPOCH.

But if I test this value in the website [Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/), I get

- GMT: Thursday 9 December 2021 15:17:44
- Your time zone: jeudi 9 décembre 2021 16:17:44 GMT+01:00

It seems that the website ALSO subtracts my timezone to an already "substracted" value, ending in removing twice the timezone and causing an invalid value.

The actual confusion is when I tried to import that UTC timestamp to Luxon on my front app, doing the following doesn't work :

```
DateTime.fromMillis(parseInt(ts), { zone: 'utc' }).toLocal().setLocale('en')
```

I'm one hour behind.

How can I "tell" Luxon that the current TS is in the UTC timezone, and calling `toLocal` will apply the proper user's timezone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that the website ALSO substract my timezone t

No, epochconverter.com isn't doing anything. The value 1639063064 really *does* represent 2021-12-09T15:17:44Z. That's not the value you want.

I'm no Python expert, but I believe the problem is the combination of [this `utcnow()` behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) (emphasis mine):

> Return the current UTC date and time, with `tzinfo None`.
>
> This is like `now()`, but returns the current UTC date and time, **as a naive datetime object.**

And [this `timestamp()` behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp):

> Naive datetime instances are assumed to represent local time and this method relies on the platform C `mktime()` function to perform the conversion.

It sounds like you want to follow this advice:

> An aware current UTC datetime can be obtained by calling `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`.

So just change your first line to:

```py
dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

... and it should be okay.

Comment: Wow! I never thought .timestamp would  be based on the local time !... That was clearly my mistake ! Thank you for that !